# Doing license check against Google on my server

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am aiming at doing my license check with google server at my own server. I couldn't find a tutorial online or posts on how to do that. Is there a google api that I can use or how would you do it (ensure that the copy is legitimate)?

Thank you

Comment: You can offload your licensing check to your own server. Infact it is is one of the recommended ways to beat piracy

Comment: Where is this recommended?